# Suppress same label from different features QGis

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

Is there a way to suppress same labels from different features other than merging the features or manually deleting the labels?

As you can see in the image below, I have multiple lines with the same label. I tried to create a buffer around the labels in order to reduce the amount of labels, but this messes up the labels of other features.

For instance: Is it possible to create a buffer for a certain string? 
So, that there is only one "B14" allowed in a certain radius.

[image]

Comment: I guess you have several lines for each street? You could build multilines, reducing the features that are available for labeling.

Comment: In this particular case you guessed right, but I have same problem for points as well and therefore looking for a more global solution.

Answer (score 8):

For lines, you can use the labeling option `merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels`.

As for your comment on buffering the labels, it can be done in the `buffer` tab but doing so will also prevent labels from other layers / features from being displayed.

[image: Label Merge connected lines]

Comment: The merge option is already activated in the op image, so this doesn´t solve my issue. And as I already mentioned in the op the standard buffer isn´t an option for me since it messes up the rest of the feature labels.

Comment: Option not available in QGIS 3.12

Answer (score 5):

I've done this in the past by making a separate labels layer with transparent points. You can merge the features and get the centre point to get a rough placement and then move as appropriate.[image]

Comment: This would be a solution, but it comes with a lot of manual editing and this will be very time consuming for the quite large amount of labels I have to deal with. But If there is no automatic way of solving this problem this will have to do..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with identical geometries in overlapping layers and would like to remove the labels while still showing the point clusters.

It may be possible to work with rules - In my own use case, I was able to fix the problem using rule-based labels:

1) My first rule excluded all towns with more than one feature from my list (e.g. "Town"!='Newport') and showed labels only for places with a single feature.
2) The second rule added labels for the previously exluded places based on a "function" that only occurs once ("Function"='moss collection centre').

That is the best fix I could find without installing additional plug-ins. There might be better solutions, e.g. using Python.

[image]

It seems this is also an [issue in ArcGIS](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007158)